# Swift 3 delete UITableView row by ID from SQLite

Tags: ios, sqlite, uitableview, swift3

I'm attempting to remove a record from an SQLite database by swiping on a tableView row. What I want to happen is by swiping then tapping Delete, the record is removed from the database. Right now, the swipe delete removes the record from the tableView but not from the database.

Here is my code:

Model Manager for SQLite database:

```
func deletePeople(profileInfo: ProfileInfo) -> Bool {
    database.open()
    var deleted = false

    defer {
        database.close()
        print("profile deleted")
    }

    if openDatabase() {
        let sql = "DELETE FROM Profiles WHERE ID=?"

    do {
        try database.executeQuery(sql, values: [profileInfo.profileID])
        deleted = true
    } catch {
        print("profile deleted")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

  }

    return deleted
}
```

ProfileInfo class:

```
class ProfileInfo: NSObject {

var profileID: String = String()
var firstName: String = String()
var lastName: String = String()
var age: Int = 0

init(profileID: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int) {
    self.profileID = profileID
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.age = age
}

override var description: String {
    return "\(profileID), \(firstName), \(lastName), \(age)"
}
}
```

tableView editing methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        profiles.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        tableView.reloadData()
        print("profile deleted")

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you should call deletePeople(profiles[indexPath.row]) before profiles.remove(at: indexPath.row) as per now you only delete from your local copy of what in the database

Comment: Thank you @MohamedMostafa that worked!